# С++ удаление элемента бинарного дерева

Tags: c++

Написала функцию для удаления элемeнтов дерева. Нужно именно поэлементно,а не только всего дерева. У меня она вроде компилируется, но сразу после запуска консоли программа пишет об ошибке и соответственно консоль работает не так, как до написания функции. В чем тут может быть проблема:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
struct Node 
{
   int x; 
   Node *l,*r;

};
void show(Node *&Tree) 
{
    if (Tree!=NULL)  
    {
      show(Tree->l); 
      show(Tree->r); 
    }
}
void add_node(int x,Node *&MyTree) 
 {
  if (MyTree) 
    {
      if (x < MyTree->x)
        add_node(x, MyTree->l);
      else
        add_node(x, MyTree->r); 
    } else 
    {
    MyTree=new Node; 
    MyTree->x=x; 
    MyTree->l=MyTree->r=NULL; 
    }
}
int cntx (Node *Tree, int deep) 
{
   if (!Tree || deep < 0) return 0;
   if (deep == 0) return 1; 
   return cntx(Tree->l, --deep) + cntx(Tree->r, --deep);
}
void sumx (Node *Tree, int x[], int nx ) 
{
   for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++)
      cout << "level: " << x[i] << ' ' << cntx(Tree, x[i]) << " Nodes\n";
}
Node* destroy(Node *Tree)
{

    if( Tree->l == 0 )
    {

        Node* right = Tree->r;

        *Tree = *right;

        right->l = 0;
        right->r = 0;
        delete right;
    } 
    else

    {

        Node *c = Tree->l;

        Node *p = Tree->l;

        while( c->r )
        {
            p = c;
            c = c->r;
        }

        p->r = c->l;

        c->l = NULL;

        Tree->x = c->x;

        delete c;
    }
    return Tree;
}

Node* remove(Node *Tree, int x)
{

    if( Tree == NULL )
        return 0;

    if( Tree->x < x )
    {

        Tree->r = remove(Tree->r, x);
        return Tree;
    }
    else

    if( x < Tree->x )
    {

        Tree->l = remove(Tree->l, x);
        return Tree;
    }

    return destroy(Tree);
}

void DeleteTree(Node *Tree)
{
  if (Tree) 
  {
      DeleteTree(Tree->l);
      DeleteTree(Tree->r);
      delete Tree;
  }
}

int main()
{
  Node *Tree=NULL;  
  int z,k;
  cout << "vvedit kilkist\n";
  cin >> z;
  for (int i=0;i<z;i++) 
  {
      cout << "vvedit chisla\n";
    cin >> k;
    add_node(k,Tree);
  }
show(Tree);
 cout << "All Tree levels cnt nodes\n";
  int n;
  for (int i = 0; n = cntx(Tree, i); i++)
    cout << n << " nodes on level " << i << '\n';
 DeleteTree(Tree);
destroy(Tree);
system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы бы очень помогли, если бы

* Сказали, в какой строчке сообщение об ошибке и какое
* Посмотрели в отладчике, какие значения у переменных в этой строчке
* Убрали из текста программы всё ненужное

Comment: Пишет:
 "Ваша программа вызвала нарушение доступа(ошибка сегментации)"
подсвечивает эту строку
 while( c->r )

Answer (score 1):

```
DeleteTree(Tree);
destroy(Tree);
```

`DeleteTree` удаляет все элементы дерева. После вызова этой функции дерева уже не существует, указатель `Tree` указывает в случайную область памяти. Далее в функции `destroy` идет обращение в эту случайную область памяти, срабатывает защита памяти и выбрасывается исключение, о чём Вам говорит отладчик.